# Which to use: OneToOne vs ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

My understanding is that OneToOneField is used for just 1 row of data from ***Table2*** (Favorite fruit) linked to one row of data in *Table1* (Person's name), and ForeignKey is for multiple rows of data in ***Table2*** (Car models) to 1 row of data in ***Table1*** (Brand/Manufacturer).

My question is what should I use if I have multiple tables but only one row of data from each table that links back to ***Table1***. For example: I have Table1 as "Cars", my other tables are "Insurance Info", "Car Info", "Repair History". Should I use ForeignKey or OneToOne?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to ask yourself "Can object A have many object B, or object B many object A's"?

Those table relations each could be different:

1. A Car could have 1 or many insurance policies, and an insurance policy only applies to one car. If the car can only have one, then it could be a one-to-one.
2. A Car can have many repair history rows, so this would be a foreign key on the repair history, with a back relation to the Car as a set.
3. Car Info is similar to the UserProfile concept in django. If it is truly unique information, then it too would be a one-to-one. But if you define Car Info as a general description that could apply to similar Car models, then it would be a foreign key on the Car Table to refer to the Car Info

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Very straightforward and easy to understand. :)

Comment: Sure thing. If you need extra info let me know. Otherwise don't forget to hit the checkmark if this solves your problem

Answer (score 3):

ForeignKey means that you are referencing an element that exists inside of another table.
OneToOne, is a type of ForeignKey in which an element of table1 and table2 are uniquely bound together.

Your favorite fruit example would be OneToMany. Because each person has a unique favorite fruit, but each fruit can have multiple people who list that particular fruit as their favorite.

A OneToOne relationship may be done with your Car example. Cars.VIN could have a OneToOne relationship with CarInfo.VIN since one car will only ever have one CarInfo associated with it (and vise versa).